# Data Cleaning, excluding specific values from data (keep missing observation) in R

Tags: r

*I have a data set with the missing observations. I was wondering how to exclude only values 10 or >30 from a data set while retaining the missing observations. The following function only retains non-missing values, whereas I need to retain all missing values and those between 10 and 30. Therefore, how do I modify the code?*

```
E <- A %>% filter(rv_div_tlc >=10) %>%  filter(rv_div_tlc <=30)
```